# Нужен класс, который сможет создавать копии класса, который передали в методе в Java

Tags: java

Вообщем, есть класс:

```java
class Manager {
    private static HashMap<String, MyObject> objects = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
    
    public static void add(String name, MyObject obj) {
        objects.put(name, obj);
    }
    
    public static MyObject get(String name) {
        // Нужно вернуть новую копию класса, как:
        // return new MyObject();
        // но создавая экземпляр неизвестного класса, который наследуется от MyObject, при этом имея его другой экземпляр (который передали в add)
    }
}
```

Как мне реализовать метод **get** в этом классе?

P.s.Если так нельзя, то может можно использовать namespace или что-то типо этого?

Comment: как на счет паттерна прототип, который уже реализован в джаве из коробки через интерфейс Cloneable ? слышали о таком?

Comment: @Дмитрий, что-то где-то видел, не расскажите подробнее?

Comment: а какой смысл? гугл на запрос java cloneable выдает 1000 страниц на всех языках с подробным описанием и примерами. поскольку вы уже знаете в каком направлении думать и что искать,  не думаю, что смогу объяснить лучше

Comment: @Дмитрий, логично, спасибо за то что направили)

Comment: да не за что, пользуйтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания нового экземпляра класса, который наследуется от MyObject, можно использовать рефлексию в Java. Пример реализации метода get():

```
public static MyObject get(String name) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {
    MyObject obj = objects.get(name);
    Class cls = obj.getClass();
    return (MyObject) cls.newInstance();
}
```

В этом примере мы используем метод get() из HashMap для получения экземпляра класса MyObject. Затем мы используем метод getClass() для получения объекта Class, соответствующего этому экземпляру. Используя метод newInstance() объекта Class, мы можем создать новый экземпляр этого класса и вернуть его как MyObject.

Однако, этот код может вызвать исключения IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException, которые нужно обработать. Поэтому в сигнатуре метода get() добавлены соответствующие исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Фактически данная задача сводится к тому, чтобы динамически создавать экземпляры объектов по строковым ключам.  Действительно, для решения такой задачи можно использовать клонирование или рефлексию, но оба упомянутых способа не являются рекомендованными в общем случае по ряду причин.

- Проблемы клонирования:

  - Необходимы изменения в родительском классе `MyObject` -- он должен реализовать маркерный интерфейс `Cloneable`, предоставить корректную реализацию метода `clone`, включая вызов `super.clone()`
  - Может понадобиться дополнительное глубокое копирование для полей-контейнеров в классе MyObject или его потомках, так как по умолчанию `Object::clone` предоставляет только поверхностное (shallow) копирование
  - Отсутствует контроль над созданием объектов, так как клонирование не использует конструкторы, в частности над изменением значений финальных полей.
- Проблемы рефлексии:

  - `Class::newInstance` является устаревшим (deprecated), [начиная с Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--), так как он маскирует любые проверяемые исключения (checked exceptions), которые могут возникнуть при создании объектов; рекомендуется использовать метод [`Constructor::newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-), где можно использовать перегруженные конструкторы с параметрами и придётся обрабатывать исключение `InvocationTargetException`.
  - Излишнее усложнение кода

Альтернативой предложенным решениям с точки зрения чистоты кода являются копирующие конструкторы вида `MyObject(MyObject copy)`, соответствующие конструкторы потребуется реализовать и в классах-потомках.

Также стоит обдумать, насколько необходимой является динамическая структура для получения экземпляров нужного класса по строковому ключу.  Фактически, метод `get(String name)` можно реализовать как мини-фабрику при помощи `switch`, создавая объекты с нужными параметрами:

```java
public static MyObject(String name) {
    return switch(name) {
        case "Parent" -> new MyObject();
        case "Son" -> new MyObjectChild("son");
        case "GrandSon" -> new MyObjectGrandChild("grandson", 123);
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Если всё-таки динамичность критично важна, можно организовать мапу функций-создателей `Supplier<? extends MyObject>`, в которую следует записывать ссылки на соответствующие дефолтные конструкторы / фабричные методы:

```java
private static Map<String, Supplier<? extends MyObject>> builders = new HashMap<>();

public static void add(String name, Supplier<? extends MyObject> builder) {
    builders.put(name, builder);
}

public static MyObject get(String name) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(builders.get(name))
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .orElseThrow();
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    add("mo", MyObject::new);
    add("foo33", () -> new Foo(33));
      
    System.out.println(get("foo33"));
}
```